# Node.js, Socket.io: How to get client browser-language?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, locale

I am trying to get the language the user uses in order to serve the right sound files for a playing video, using socket.io and node.js.
I am a total beginner with node.js and socket.io. I got the language on client side with "navigator.language" and wanted to send it when connecting/handshaking to socket.io.

```
var language = navigator.language;
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1337', { query: language });
```

And on server-side:

```
io.set('authorization', function(handshakeData, cb) {
    console.log(handshakeData.query);
    cb(null, true);});
```

But what I get is:

```
{'en-US': 'undefined', t: '1396002389530'}
```

I guess the second attribute "t" is the handshake ID that has been added. But how do I access 'en-US'?

---

My second approach was to use the module "locale" (https://github.com/jed/locale), but when I used that, I always got the same language, so I figured that it always finds the SERVER's language. I thought I use it in the request/response handler, when a new client requests the page and sends its http header.

```
var handler = function(req, res) {
    lang = new locale.Locales(req.headers["accept-language"]);
    lang=lang.best(supported);
    console.log(pf);
}
```

I hope you get what I am trying to do and maybe know a better solution. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there.
Do this:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1337', { lang: language });
```

Instead of `{query: language}` because query is a reserved object.

And you can access this by doing this:

```
io.set('authorization', function(handshakeData, cb) {
console.log(handshakeData.query.lang);
cb(null, true);});
```

You can also access it like this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log(socket.handshake.query.lang);
});
```

If you don't want to append language variable to `query` then you can access the language by this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log(socket.handshake.headers['accept-language']);
});
```

Comment: I tried it, but its returning "undefined", since somehow it rearranges the array as seen above "{'en-US': 'undefined', t: '1396002389530'}". so the actual language is the variablename and its value is "undefined". I dont know why. It doesnt even matter what I append to "handshakeData.query" like lang or blabla, its always undefined. so it cannot find the name

Comment: Believe me or not its working in my PC. Is navigator.language also undefined in your browser?

Comment: really? thats strange. can you think of another solution how to get the users language setting?

Comment: I got it working with your last approach, but I get "de-DE,de;q0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=04" how can I filter the language, just slice the first 2 characters of that string?

Comment: Yeah I think so it depends on your logic. I want to ask 1 thing, did u do var lang = navigator.language and then var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1337', { lang: language }); ???

Comment: yes, first the variable initiation and then the socket connect. But wait, I got the header information, but somehow its not the information of the client, since my client has en-US as the browser language. It shows correctly on clientside "en-US" (navigator.language), but the header shows "de-DE" on my console with your handshake header.do you know why?

Comment: I've tested it in Mozilla Firefox and chrome and it shows me the language of browser. I'm sorry I don't know why is it showing you a different language since headers always have the information what client sends.

Comment: ok thanks man, I changed my Operating system language and tried internet explorer, and now its working. I dont know why chrome still sends the german header even though I changed the language to english. anyways. thanks. To think further, do you think its possible to stream a video and change the language for different users whenever they connect?

Comment: Yeah just google Video streaming with socket.io and you'll find a lot.There are modules such as socket.io stream and socket stream which might serve your purpose