# Supporting Localization on Socket.io using query parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Am trying to support different languages with *socket-io*, and from what I understand using *Headers* is out of the question so am left with the *query parameter*.
A user can **switch language not on first connection only**, but multiple times on the client-side by adding a query value on every emitted message that will be caught on server-side.

At the first connection I added the query value to the options it worked, but for the next emitted requests I am unable to capture the new query value. Is their a method like a node middleWare to capture the selected language for socket-io on server side.

This is the client code I connect in English then switched to French:

```
const options = {
   transports: ['websocket'],
   'force new connection': true,
   query: {lang: 'en'}
};
const client = io.connect(socketURL, options)
client.on('connect', () => {
   client.emit('create', '/note', payload, {lang: 'fr'}, (err, data) => {
      console.log(data.title); // should be in French but its in English     
      client.disconnect();
   });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js, Socket.io: How to get client browser-language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710448/node-js-socket-io-how-to-get-client-browser-language)

Comment: Thanks but that answers only on first connection, not on subsequent requests using emit were a user can switch language.

Comment: A WebSocket connection is only a single bi-directional connection. The concept of a request does not apply to WebSocket connections, only events. The language selected will always be on the `socket` object throughout the connection's lifetime.

Comment: Are You saying WebSocket does not support switching language and events emitted cant be used to do that throughout the connection's lifetime....shame

Comment: What I'm saying is that you are able to access the `socket` object in your `socket.on(...)` server-side code, so you can at any point re-assign `socket.handshake.query.lang` to something else server-side. Instead of sending a `lang` property *on each `emit`*, have a dedicated `emit` that tells the server that all subsequent messages exchanged from this point should be in X language. Server-side you just re-assign the `socket.handshake.query.lang` to the language the client told you to, and when you emit something server-side, you check this property to determine what language to use.